# How do I decrease letter spacing in java.awt.font?

Tags: java, string, swing, graphics

I'm trying to make a graph with a numbered axis. However, I can't seem to decrease the spacing between these numbers. Here is the current code I am using to decrease the spacing between the numbers in my `paintComponent` method, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
super.paintComponent(g);

Map<TextAttribute, Object> attributes = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.TRACKING, 0.5);

Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 1);
Font font2 = font.deriveFont(attributes);

g.setFont(font2);
```

When the numbers are displayed, the space between them is the same as before.

I've tried reducing the 0.5 in the `attributes.put()` method, but it doesn't seem to reduce the spacing. I've also tried `TextAttribute.KERNING` and using `TextAttribute.KERNING_ON`, but that didn't work out either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: From `TextAttribute.TRACKING` JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) : "Tracking values are typically between -0.1 and 0.3; values outside this range are generally not desireable."

Comment: D'oh! Never tried negative numbers. -0.5 seems to eliminate all spacing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From TextAttribute.TRACKING [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html) :

> Tracking values are typically between -0.1 and 0.3; values outside
>   this range are generally not desireable.

Comment: p.s that is how "desireable" is spelled in the source.